# How do I keep displaying a model with vuforia image targets when the target is lost

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am working on an indoor navigation app in Unity that uses image targets to display a navigation line when the target is found but when the image target goes off screen the objects that appear will disappear, I want to know how to keep the objects that appear on screen. I guess that the "on target lost" function would be used but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the observer when the target goes off screen is controlled by the Extended-Tracking flag (see here https://library.vuforia.com/device-tracking/enable-device-tracking-unity). Note that the DeviceTracker must be enabled for this to work.